# How to include font into document?

Tags: fonts, warnings

I have a template that use Frutiger Font. But I think the font is not correctly included because while generating the document I get various font errors and the last one:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

So how can I included that font?

Comment: you choose a fontshape which is not available. It is listed after the above warning. For example `\scshape\slshape` is not possible

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This messages are not errors but warnings/informations. They inform you that a certain combination of font features (e.g. a tt-font in bold + italic + small caps) doesn't exist and that LaTeX used a fallback. This messages are quite common and in more than 90% of all cases the substitution is ok.