# LaTeX Font Warning on Natty Ubuntu Linux

Tags: fonts, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to include font into document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10178/how-to-include-font-into-document)
>   ["Font shape undefined" with latex and isodoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24628/font-shape-undefined-with-latex-and-isodoc)

I am using the following in a document:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{tgothic}
\usepackage{libertine}
```

I am using Ubuntu Natty and I am getting the following warning:

```
 LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

I must be missing a package but I am not sure which one?

Comment: This is a warning when using specific features, such as small caps for example. You'll have to see which of these features you're trying to use with which font. The rest of the log should help you.

Comment: Also: If you haven't manually installed TeXlive 2010 or 2011, you're running TeXlive 2009 if you're using Ubuntu. It's *hopelessly* outdated, and they're not showing any signs of updating it for Oneric either (I think)

Comment: @kahen: Oh.. That would be a problem indeed.  Thanks.